# Cannot access updated data from useReducer hook in function defined in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, use-reducer

In my application, I'm using a dispatch from useReducer hook on click of a button and in the same function I'm using a setTimeout of 2 seconds. But when I store the data using dispatch of usereducer then I'm not getting updated value in setTimeout function.

I cannot share original code, but sharing a snippet of another demo app where this issue occurs.

```
const initialData = { data: "ABC" };

function reducer(state = initialData, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "STORE":
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
      break;
  }
}
function Demo() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialData);
  console.log("Render : ",state.data);  //Will be executed on each rendering
  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "STORE",
      payload: state.data + parseInt(Math.random() * 10)
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("ButtonClick : ",state.data); //Will be executed after 2 seconds of dispatching.
    }, 2000);
  };
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{state.data}</button>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

In above example I'm storing data in reducer using dispatch, and I'm calling console.log("ButtonClick") on Button Click after 2 seconds but even after 2 seconds, I'm not getting updated data in console. But in console.log("Render") I'm getting updated data.

Live example on : https://codepen.io/aadi-git/pen/yLJLmNa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
const handleClick = () => {
  dispatch({
    type: "STORE",
    payload: state.data + parseInt(Math.random() * 10)
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("ButtonClick : ",state.data); //Will be executed after 2 seconds of dispatching.
  }, 2000);
};
```

this is what happens:

1. Run `dispatch` with an object to store some data. This function is executed asynchronically, so the result is not available immediately.
2. Register a timeout handler, which logs the current value of `state.data` to the console. Since the preceding `dispatch` is still working in progress, the value of `state.data` is still the old one.

   This means you can not log a new dispatched value by running `console.log` after your `dispatch` call because you can not see into the future. You can only log the new data after a re-render of your component due to changing state. Then you can and should use

   ```
   React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log(state.data);
   }, [state.data]);
   ```

#### Some more explanations about `setTimeout` and why `console.log` logs old values within it

You use

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("ButtonClick : ", state.data);
}, 2000);
```

and this is equivalent to

```
const callback = () => console.log("ButtonClick : ", state.data);
setTimeout(callback, 2000);
```

In the first line you create a function (named `callback` here), which prints some text. This text consists of a simple string and the value of `state.data`. Therefore this function has a **reference to the variable `state.data`**. The function in combination with the reference to the outer state is called [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#:%7E:text=A%20closure%20is%20the%20combination,scope%20from%20an%20inner%20function.) and this closure ensures, that the value `state.data` is kept alive as long as the function lives (is not binned by the garbage collector).

In the second line `setTimeout` is called with this function. Simplified this means a task is stored somewhere which states, that exactly this function has to be executed after the given timeout. So as long as this task is not done, the function stays alive and with it the variable `state.data`.

In the meantime long before the task is handled, the new action is `dispatch`ed, new state calculated and `Demo` re-rendered. With that a new `state.data` and a new `handleClick` is created. With the new creation of `handleClick` also a new function is created which is passed to `setTimeout`. This whole `handleClick` function is then passed as `onClick` handler for the `button` element.

The re-render is now over, but the task from before is still pending. Now when the timeout duration ends (long after re-rendering the component) the task is taken from the task queue and executed. The task still has reference to the function from the render before and this function still has reference to the value `state.data` from the render before. So the value logged to the console is still the old value from the render before.

Comment: Even if the dispatch is asynchronous it will definitely not take 2 seconds to execute. And my setTimeout will run the callback inside it after 2 seconds, so it should have the latest value.

Comment: Yes, yes, but no. Read my added explanation, I hope this explains it a little better, what is going on.

Comment: Thank you, Understood properly. Can we find a solution to this? I mean I have to access the data in setTimeout callback. Currently to avoid this problem I'm using useRef hook and storing value into that instead of the reducer. And accessing the value in callback of setTimeout. This works but I don't think it's the ideal way.

Comment: You mean, you must log the text with the data two seconds after data has changed?

Comment: Not log, it was for demonstration. But I am handling some operations in place of console.log.

Comment: Ok, then I would just go with `React.useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => doSomeStuffWith(state.data), 2000), [state.data]);` directly in `Demo`. But take care for `state.data` updates in between.

Comment: I will check this solution out. Thank you for precise explanation.